# Who did what exactly for the original Shadowgate (1987) Macintosh video game?

Tags: history, apple-macintosh, gaming, software-development, game

I primarily know Shadowgate from the wonderful NES port, which was ported by some Japanese company and whose Japanese musician composed the beautiful, iconic music which I frankly thought was there all along. This turned out to be false; the original game was entirely mute, save for some ridiculous sound effects. Having only learned about the original many years later, it seemed sterile and dead in comparison.

The original game lists the credits here: https://www.mobygames.com/game/macintosh/shadowgate/credits

> David Feldman, David Marsh, Terry Schulenburg, Karl Roelofs, Jay Zipnick, Todd Squires, Darin Adler, Tod Zipnick, Waldemar Horwat, Steven Hays

Sadly, they are all bundled together under a generic "Staff" label; there's no telling who actually did what. Frequently, there are just a couple of actual programmers/designers/graphics artists, with several members of a staff/team just being responsible for the business side and marketing and all that stuff, which really has nothing to do with the actual game itself. (But of course is still very important -- crucial even -- for the game to actually find an audience.)

I've long searched and tried to figure out the "real" credits. I want to know exactly who did what. I don't think that it's ever the case that all these people would sit in a room and "do a little here and a little there"; that's just not how things work. Maybe they would give minor idea input and things like that, but I'm convinced that there must have been a subset of those listed individuals who did the "actual work" for that classic game.

Note that, while I'm *also* interested in the answer to the same question for *Déjà Vu*, I primarily am asking about the original *Shadowgate* for Macintosh and not the other games in the "MacVenture" series.

Comment: David Marsh, from your list, is a prolific game developer and is responsible for the continuation of the Shadowgate "franchise" until now. He is likely the best living source of who did exactly what in 1987. But clearly the concept came from Marsh and Roelofs, and Adler was the head developer.

Comment: This borderline looks like a question about game ‘content’ rather than its software mechanics. As such, it probably should have been asked on Arqade.

Comment: I have to agree. This is really only about content. Not a bad question, but not really fir for RC.SE. Maybe this should be moved over to [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) ?